# how to use User class in Django

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

I wrote a user-login function, but it just not work

This is the models.py

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    Userinfo = models.OneToOneField(User)
    join_time = models.DateTimeField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.Userinfo.username
```

and this is the userlogin in  views.py

```
def Userlogin(request):
    uf = UserForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if uf.is_valid():
            uf = UserForm(request.POST)
            username = uf.cleaned_data['username']
            password = uf.cleaned_data['password']
            user = models.UserProfile.authenticate(
                username=username,password=password)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    login(request, user)
                    return render(request,
                        'UserLogin/index.html',{'username':username})
            else:
                return HttpResponse('password is not matched')
    return render(request, 'UserLogin/login.html',{'uf':uf})
```

I read the document of django many times but i think i didn't really understand.
So is my way of using User model correct? this is really confusing..

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/customizing/

Comment: what error are you getting here?

Comment: oh sorry ..i forget the error ...  it's'UserForm' object has no attribute 'cleaned_data'

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that you are reassignning the value of the form after validate it. When you mas `is_valid()`, if it is, you will be able to access to `cleaned data`, but not before. Try to change your just commenting the recond uf assignation:

```
def Userlogin(request):
    uf = UserForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if uf.is_valid():
            #uf = UserForm(request.POST)
            username = uf.cleaned_data['username']
            password = uf.cleaned_data['password']
```